# In Selenium, how to click on an element under HMTL under iframe. So the hierarchy from big to small: iframe>#document>HTML. I added the scrreenshot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1feJn.png)

I switched to that iframe but still unable to reach in the elements under HTML. Please be aware #document has no a css selector or xpath, I think it is not an element. Thank you for your help in adcance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `By.ID` locator strategy as below:

```
# To switch into the desired IFRAME
iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "remote_iframe_0")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(iframe))

# perform desired actions here within the IFRAME

# To come out of iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```